# How to get a widget to move across the screen every X seconds?

Tags: flutter

Basically I'm trying to build a game to learn flutter more.

Right now I'm just trying to get a Text widget to move from the top of the phone screen, towards the bottom of the phone screen... I'm building a Space Invaders type of game with just Text.

From what I've read by googling the problem, should I use Flame? Or can everything be done by just using the base Flutter framework (collision detection, moving widgets, etc...)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to solve this problem is to have the moving Text widget a child of the Stack() widget. Actually, the child of the Stack() widget is a Positioned() widget, which has **left** and **top** properties, which you can update periodically with a Timer.periodic function to move the widget down by incrementing **top** property.  So, your Text widget is a child of the Positioned() widget, that you use for, well, positioning.

I have a working example of this in my [slowly_moving_widgets_field](https://github.com/remoteportal/slowly_moving_widgets_field) project, where I have a bunch of arbitrary widgets moving about the screen every X seconds as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Draggable` class for dragging the item.